# How to use AWS SSM parameter for token in provider github?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

This is the code snippet in my main.tf file:

```
provider "github" {
  token        = var.github_token_ssm
  owner        = var.owner
}
data "github_repository" "github" {
  full_name = var.repository_name
}
```

The github token is stored in AWS secretsmanager parameter.

If the value of the token is hardcoded github token, then it works fine.
If the value of the token is a AWS secretsmanager parameter (eg. arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:secret:xxxx-Github-t0UOOD:xxxxxx), it is not working.

I don't want to hardcode github token in the code. How can I use secretsmanager parameter for token above?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Terraform not supporting aws Secret Manager (but you can use the vault to store secrets).
you can also deploy it with TF_VAR variable and ENV Var
export TF_VAR_db_username=admin TF_VAR_db_password=adifferentpassword
You can also run a script that will pull the secret from aws and store it in EnvVar.

just remember to secure your state file (the password will exist in clear text)